# In Powershell: Remove lines from a text file if it contains a set words stored in another text file

Tags: powershell

I know:

```
Get-Content C:\new\temp_*.txt | Select-String -pattern "H|159" -notmatch | Out-File C:\new\newfile.txt
```

But i need to fetch `-pattern` from another text file as the patterns are 300k so cannot be piped.

What is the modified command?

Comment: `$pattern = Get-Content fileWithRegexPattern.txt`?

Comment: Get-Content test.txt | Select-String $pattern = Get-Content ex.txt -notmatch | Out-File newfile.txt
Select-String : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Pattern' because it is null.
At line:1 char:38
+ Get-Content test.txt | Select-String $pattern = Get-Content ex.txt -n ...
+                                      ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Select-String], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStrin
   gCommand

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: `$pattern = Get-Content fileWithRegexPattern.txt; Get-Content text.txt |Select-String -Pattern $pattern`

Comment: This works for selecting contents that match pattern.  -notmatch does not work.  Anyways, task will be accomplished. thanks.

Comment: Get-Content test.txt | Select-String $pattern = Get-Content ex.txt -notmatch | Out-File newfile.txt
Select-String : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Get-Content'.
At line:1 char:24
+ ...  test.txt | Select-String $pattern = Get-Content ex.txt -notmatch | O ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-String], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern will take an array of patterns, which can just as easily be the result of `Get-Content` of another file.  Select-String emits objects, so if your're hoping the matched lines are going to be in he file it's going to be wrong.

In that case it will show the filename the line number and the matched line.

To get just the lines try something like:

```
$Pattern = Get-Content <SomeFile.txt>
(Select-String -path C:\new\temp_*.txt -Pattern $pattern).Line | Out-File C:\new\newfile.txt
```

- Establishing the `$Pattern` variable as an array of patterns sourced from a file
- Instead of piping the files to select string use the -Path parameter with the wildcard pattern.
- Then reference & pipe the line property of the match objects instead of piping the objects themselves to the file.

This will result in only the matching lines being present in the output file.

let me know if that helps.

Comment: Didn't try this. Task accomplished

Comment: @Mike You may not know this because you're new to the platform, but if this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the faint checkmark icon next to it. This will help others finding it more easily and works as motivation for people to answer your future questions.

Answer (score 0):

$pattern = Get-Content fileWithRegexPattern.txt; Get-Content text.txt |Select-String -Pattern $pattern

and pipe the output.